# Python pip package not executable after developing from Windows

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-packaging

I am creating a python pip package. After uploading it to pypi, I installed it locally and tried calling the python package. Instead of executing the python script in it, It opened the script in my text editor.

When Googled, I found that I have to set chmod +x for my script.

But I am developing this from Windows 7. How to resolve this?

Comment: How about running `python -m <your_package_name>`?

Comment: `python -m yourpackagenamehere` or bind .py extension to Python interpreter (all double-clicking on .py files will start the file)